# Ejabberd offline messages

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have set up a chat server with Ejabberd, It is working fine. Messages are getting sent from one user to another user. Problem is that when the receiving user is offline, Sender messages should get stored and get delivered to receiver when he comes back to online. But offline messages are not getting delivered. I have not changed anything in configuration file because it looks already configured for the offline storage and offline message delivery. Do I need to make any other changes apart from the below lines?

ejabberd.cfg:

```
{access, max_user_offline_messages, [{5000, admin}, {100, all}]}. 
{mod_offline,  [{access_max_user_messages, max_user_offline_messages}]}
```

Comment: Offline messages are maintained by ejabberd right out of the box. Which verion of ejabberd are you using?

Comment: ejabberd 2.1.10 is the version

Answer (score 0):

Please update your ejabberd from 2.1.10 to 16.10, as you using the older version certain func. may not work as expected.